# Call procedure included in oracle package

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have created a package in my Oracle database which includes several procedures, now I want to call procedure from java program procedure requires two input parameter and returns nothing.

Please help me to do so, I have been using below connection to connect to database:

```
String i =username.getText(); 
String j =psswd.getText();
String k = sid.getText();
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ora211g.home.com:1654:ora11g",username,password);
st =  con.createStatement();
rs =st.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT SUBJECT_AREA FROM REP_SUBJECT");
```

This thing is working fine, now how can I call procedure by passing some parameter (say two string values)

Answer (score 0):

This useful blog posting will help you

http://jameajudo.blogspot.com.br/2009/03/call-procedure-oracle-with-java-and.html

The example he uses is:

```
String command = "{call SALDOS(?,?)}"; 
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall (command);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.DECIMAL);

cstmt.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

2This is what you want

```
st =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT SUBJECT_AREA FROM REP_SUBJECT WHERE A = ? AND B = ?");
st.setString(1, "val1");
st.setString(2, "val2");
rs =st.executeQuery();
```

Comment: the user wants to call a procedure rather than their statement/query (judging from the question) - but thanks because I wasn't aware of the prepareStatement method

Answer (score 0):

Using [con.prepareCall()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall%28java.lang.String%29).

And then using the `CallableStatement` object that is returned for setting params and execution.

Answer (score 0):

Here I got the solution of my question so thought of posting it here so that everybody can understand in detail:

```
     Connection con = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;
       Statement st = null;
    Class.forName = Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID);

CallableStatement csmt = con.prepareCall("{call PACKAGE_NAME.PROCEDURE_NAME(?,?,?,?)}");
                        csmt.setString(1,"abc");
                        csmt.setString(2,"def");
                        csmt.setString(3,"ghi");
                        csmt.registerOutParameter(4,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                        csmt.execute();
                        String message =csmt.getString(4);
```

here '?' indicates the number of input and output parameters in your procedure. I had 3 input and 1 output parameter so number of '?' in procedure are 4.

there indexing start with 1,2,3....

my first three input parameter are a string, so i am passing them to procedure using :

```
                            csmt.setString(1,"abc");
                            csmt.setString(2,"def");
                            csmt.setString(3,"ghi");
```

my Procedure returns string, so in order to get receive that in java first I have to register the out parameter so I have done the same using :

```
csmt.registerOutParameter(4,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR); /*4 becuase out parameter is 4th*/
```

Then I have executed callable statement and after that I am receiving the return from procedure into

String message =csmt.getString(4);

Enjoy..... \M/